Not receiving data or props when using State in Link and printing on another page/jsx file
I am sending my props using state in  from ContactCard to ContactDetails Page. But when using useLocation hook, i am receiving null in Location.state.
ContactCard.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ContactCard = (props) => {
  const { id, name, email } = props.contact;

  const removeId = (id) => {
    props.getDeleteId(id);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Link
          to={{ pathname: `/ContactDetails/${id}` }}
          state={props.contact}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        >
          <i className="bi bi-person-circle"></i>
          <label className='p-1'>{name}</label>
          <label>{email}</label>
        </Link>
        <i
          className="bi bi-trash ml-10"
          onClick={() => removeId(id)}
          style={{
            cursor: "pointer",
            color: "red",
            marginLeft: "48px"
          }}
        ></i>
      </div>
      <div className='ul'></div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ContactCard;

ContactDetails.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const ContactDetails = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { contact } = location.state || {};

  if (!contact) {
    return <div>No contact data available.</div>;
  }

  console.log(contact);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>{contact.name}</div>
        <div>{contact.email}</div>
      </div>
      <div className='ul'></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ContactDetails;

Data in props.contact:
{
  id: 'ec49b94a-eebf-4111-8e7e-40ea1a72a92e',
  name: 'abc',
  email: 'xyz@gmail.com'
}

I should be able to receive the props.contact data in location.state.

The code is passing props.contact as the route state, i.e. state={props.contact}, but props.contact doesn't have any contact property on it.
const { id, name, email } = props.contact;

Either access id, name, and email directly from location.state:
const location = useLocation();
const { id, name, email } = location.state || {};

Or pass the contact details into state.contact:
<Link
  to={`/ContactDetails/${id}`}
  state={{ contact: props.contact }} // location.state.contact 
  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
>
  <i className="bi bi-person-circle"></i>
  <label className='p-1'>{name}</label>
  <label>{email}</label>
</Link>

